# Re-instancing a class after autoloading with Rails and RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, autoload

I have this Class where I created some attributes depending on a database table:

```
class Form
 include ActiveAttr::Model

 attribute :type, type: String
 attribute :default_name, type: String

 Languages.all.each do |lang|
  attribute :"name_#{lang}", type: String
 end
end
```

This works fine, but then I made two tests with RSpec:

Unit Test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Form, type: :class do
  ...
end
```

E2E Test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'forms', type: :system do
  let!(:languages) do
    create(:language, name: 'es')
    create(:language, name: 'en')
  end

  scenario 'accessing the page where I can see all the attributes of the Form' do
    @form = create(:form, :with_languages)
    visit form_page(@form)
  end

  ...
```

When I run `rspec` Rails autoloads everything and the Form class is created without any Language in the database yet, so it hasn't any `name_` attribute. The first test works fine, but the second one fails because the Form Class was loaded without the Languages mocked:

```
undefined method `name_en' for #<Form:0x000000014766c4f0>
```

This is because in order to load the view, we do `@view = Form.new(@form)` in the controller. And apparently it doesn't create a new object.

If I only run the second test it works like a charm, I tried with DatabaseCleaner but it's the same.

Is there a way to do this without disabling autoloading? I tried disabling it with `config.autoload_paths` but it gives me thousands of errors and it's a huge app.

I tried several solutions but none of them work, what I need is to re-create that class.

Answer (score 0):

`@view = Form.new(@form)` does create a new object but it doesn't reload the class, so attributes do not get defined again. `attribute` is a class method it runs when `Form` class is loaded, it doesn't run when `Form.new` is called.

I'm not sure what you're doing with just `Form` class, usually you'd have a specific class for each form. You could add attributes later, but it is a permanent change to `Form` class:

```rb
>> Form
# Form class is autoloaded and all attributes are defined
 Language Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "languages".* FROM "languages"
=> Form(default_name: String, type: String)

>> Language.create(name: :en)
>> Form
# will not add language attributes
=> Form(default_name: String, type: String)

>> Form.attribute :name_en, type: String
=> attribute :name_en, :type => String
>> Form
=> Form(default_name: String, name_en: String, type: String)
```

You could change `Form` class when initializing a new object:

```rb
class Form
  include ActiveAttr::Model
  attribute :type,         type: String
  attribute :default_name, type: String

  def self.lang_attributes languages = Language.pluck(:name)
    Array.wrap(languages).each do |lang|
      attribute :"name_#{lang}", type: String
    end
  end

  lang_attributes

  def initialize(...)
    self.class.lang_attributes
    super
  end
end
```

```rb
>> Language.create(name: :en)
>> Form # first call to Form autoloads it
  Language Pluck (0.8ms)  SELECT "languages"."name" FROM "languages"
=> Form(default_name: String, name_en: String, type: String)

>> Language.create(name: :es)
>> Form.lang_attributes
>> Form
=> Form(default_name: String, name_en: String, name_es: String, type: String)

>> Language.create(name: :fr)
>> my_form = Form.new
  Language Pluck (0.6ms)  SELECT "languages"."name" FROM "languages"
=> #<Form default_name: nil, name_en: nil, name_es: nil, name_fr: nil, type: nil>
# NOTE: but this changes the class itself
```

If you want the actual class to be dynamic, then the class definition has to be dynamic:

```rb
class FormClass
  def self.new langs: Language.pluck(:name)
    Class.new do
      include ActiveAttr::Model
      attribute :type,         type: String
      attribute :default_name, type: String
      Array.wrap(langs).each do |lang|
        attribute :"name_#{lang}", type: String
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
>> form_class = FormClass.new    # aka Form
  Language Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "languages".* FROM "languages"
=> (default_name: String, name_en: String, name_es: String, name_fr: String, type: String)
>> form_object = form_class.new  # aka Form.new
=> #< default_name: nil, name_en: nil, name_es: nil, name_fr: nil, type: nil>

>> Language.destroy_all
>> form_object = FormClass.new.new
  Language Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "languages".* FROM "languages"
=> #< default_name: nil, type: nil>
# no more language attributes ^

# and you can override language attribute(s) 
>> FormClass.new(langs: :en).new
=> #< default_name: nil, name_en: nil, type: nil>
```